# API guard error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, heap-memory

While building the workspace it gives the **API guard** error which is

> Function 5117 (QP5_SHL_INIT_CHUNKER): Handle (0xoB621498) Passed to
>   API seems to point to a deleted QP5 object of type SHL.

After ignoring the API guard error I get a **heap space** error which is

> An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace Java heap space error".

I tried to solve the heap space issue by making changes in **eclipse.ini** file but it still gives me the same heap space error.Changes made in **eclipse.ini** file as follows

`-Xms1024m`

`-Xmx2048m`

**Error Screenshots:**

1. [API guard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58eMS.png)
2. [heap space error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58eMS.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is difficult to answer your question, as it lacks details. Also you don't make it clear what your actual question is. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Use the [edit] button to improve your question. Thanks

Comment: hello.Thanks for your response.